# Facebook api: AdsInsights doesn't contain DevicePlatform field anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook AdsInsights contained several fields with breakdown data. For example, if VALUE_DEVICE_PLATFORM breakdown is in use then each AdsInsight should contain device_platform value.

From 2.10 API version breakdown fields were removed so, there is no option to fetch device platform of AdsInsight.

Is it bug or breakdown mechanism was changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After father investigation, I found that it's just a bug in Facebook java sdk.
DEVICE_PLATFORM and other breakdown fields exist in the json response, but parsing of the json to AdInsights pojo ignore them, since AdInsights doesn't contain appropriate filed.

There is an open issue in facebook-java-ads-sdk:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk/issues/122